# Mark a property as Unique in POCO and Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to create a POCO that has multiple fields that are unique. I have the typical Entity Id field marked with Key. But I have another field named StudentId which is of type string and needs to be unique also. Using [Key] attribute on multiple fields including the Id throws an error. I can't find any other attribute that does the job. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614575/entity-framework-code-first-unique-column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614575/entity-framework-code-first-unique-column)
for how to mark column as unique using data annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried doing this in the `CreateIndex` method?

```
CreateIndex(table: "Students", 
        column: "Name", 
        unique: true, // unique index
        name: "StudentIndex");
```

You could also try it using the `ExecuteStoreCommand`

```
context.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("CREATE UNIQUE CONSTRAINT...");
```

Comment: Thanks, I just thought there is an attribute that can handle that.

Comment: @RueLeonheart No there isn't but you can show your support for it being added in the next version by [voting for it here](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2231176-indexattribute)

Comment: I don't have the time to look now, but I'm sure there should be a way to wire up your own attribute and call it `[IndexAttribute]` whereby you can trigger the `CreateIndex` command.

Comment: Or maybe a clearer attribute might be `[CreateIndex]` with `public void CreateIndexAttribute(..){..}`