# Entity Framework ignores Column attribute

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have a large MySQL database mapped to POCOs using Entity Framework Data Annotations.

Most things work great, except one column in one table(or at least, I have not yet noticed any other similar problems).

```
mysql > describe _passwords;
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type       | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id             | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| creation_date  | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| user_id        | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| password_hash  | char(64)   | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| valid_end_date | timestamp  | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

The password_hash column is mapped like this:

```
[Required]
[Index(IsUnique=true)]
[Column("password_hash")]
public String PasswordHash
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

And yet when EF runs this query, it calls it PasswordHash, and naturally, fails.

When I try the same using Fluent API this works:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Password>().Property(password => password.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("password_hash");
```

However, everything else is mapped with Data Annotations, and frankly, I like it this way. So would rather understand the root of this problem over moving this/all mappings to Fluent API

Comment: Your issue is on `[Index(IsUnique=true)]`?

Comment: @erikscandola Why can't I set the column as unique? I can keep that check only in the database, but seems kinda silly.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the answer! I'll check it on Sunday when I'm back to work.

Comment: Have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614575/entity-framework-code-first-unique-column?

Comment: Nope, but it doesn't explain anything I didn't know before

Comment: So, you have already tried to set StringLength to 450?

Comment: Not until now, since it's not set "nvarchar(MAX)" in the db, and also, the default string length in EF is 128, so there should be no problem here. Anyway, I tried this now, and it did not help.

Comment: Removing `[Index(IsUnique=true)]` completely, on the other hand, did :) Which is nice for now, but I'd really like to know why.

Comment: With fluent api seems you have not set unique, maybe that's why it worked

Comment: Yeah, probably. Still doesn't explain why adding unique kills the whole mapping without directly throwing an exception :/ Oh well. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: because EF is a buggy crap