# Unique columns values in Entity Framework - Code First

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an entity like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }   // this is an EmailAddress

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }      
}
```

How can I define the `Username` to be unique too?

Using Entity Framework **6.1.3**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re using the newest EF (6.1+) then you can use this code:

```
[Index("UserNameIndex", IsUnique = true)]
[MaxLength(100)]
 public string UserName { get; set; }
```

With EF of earlier versions there’s more complex approach which you can check here: [Unique key with EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701608/unique-key-with-ef-code-first)

Comment: ty will try that immediately :D

Comment: I am getting this exception: "Column 'Username' in table 'dbo.Users' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index."

Comment: it seems to correspond to http://stackoverflow.com/a/23055838/4610605 can you help me out ? I don't get whats wrong ....

Comment: Try to add the MaxLength attribute. The Indexes length is limited so you have to specify the max length value for your property.