# Add Unique constraint to AspNetUsers.UserName code first with migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

How can I add a unique contraint to the AspNetUsers.UserName column using Entity Framework migrations? It seems like a jungle to me figuring out how the initial Identity tables are configured.

Answer (score 0):

To make the column unique you can use Data Annotations and the attribute `[Index(IsUnique=true)]` in your code. Please see this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614575/entity-framework-code-first-unique-column) by @juFo for more information.