# Unique DataAnnotation in ASP.NET MVC Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public string ID{ get; set; }

    [Unique]
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
}
```

The `ID` becomes the primary key. However, I want the `EmployeeID` to be a unique key as well.

Is there any data annotation to make the `EmployeeID` field unique?

These are the packages that I am using in my project:

[image: These are the packages that I am using in my project]

I have tried using `[Index(IsUnique=true)]`. But I need to install a new package for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework code first unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614575/entity-framework-code-first-unique-column)

Comment: I tried this. However, I need to install new packages in my project and I am not allowed t do so.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to install new packages?  Is that a corporate decision?  If you want a data annotation that is in a package you can't install because of corporate policies, I'm afraid you're out of luck.